# How to define variable with type of Bool ( Globals - struct ) xcode8-swift3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I write the below code in a swift file :

```
import Foundation

struct globals {

    static var test = "someString"
    static var isContentLoadedFor1Events : Bool = false
    static var isContentLoadedFor2Events : Bool = false
    static var isContentLoadedFor3events : Bool = false
    static var isContentLoadedFor4Events : Bool = false

}
```

in code at line (localMemory is `UserDefaults.standard`) :

```
localMemory.setObject( true , forKey: globals.isContentLoadedFor1Events  )
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: you are passing boolean value for string key.

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: Just to save (true or false) with Bool type , just like this example https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults

Comment: But you are passing Bool value to string.

Comment: I dont understand this is defined like Bool >> static var isContentLoadedFor1Events : Bool = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change var type to String like this -

```
import Foundation

struct globals {

    static var isContentLoadedFor1Events : String = "isContentLoadedFor1Events"

}
```

And save like this-

```
localMemory.setObject( true , forKey: globals.isContentLoadedFor1Events )
```

Comment: key is literal string i misunderstand that . Nice!